# Javascript/JQuery Variable out of function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I wrote some code so I can calculate the ingredients of a recipe I choose. I defined a variable in a `change` function. I want to take this somehow out of the function, but I don't know how I should do this.

I hope someone can help me. I need the variable `rezept` for a later function again.

```
$("select#rezept").change(function () {
    var rezept = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    console.log(rezept);
```

at the moment its in the `$(document).ready(function ()`

Comment: Create a function, containing whatever logic you need, and pass the `rezept` variable as an argument. I'm sure someone will be along to suggest using a global variable, but do not do that, it's very bad practice and with proper design principles in place, there is no need for it.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to use a select value in the function... so you don't need `onchange` for that. In `onchange` you can just shoot your function or whatever. Function itself should get it like that:

```
function myfunction(){
    var myvalue = $("select#rezept").val();
    console.log(myvalue)
}
```

And yes, use global variables (as in the other answer) only if you really need that. Using global variable in this case probably wouldn't be a good practice.

Comment: Unless you have 1000s of drop downs, get-it-when-you-need it (as detailed here) is likely the cleanest approach.  Especially for a specific `select` with an `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable outside the function and just change its value inside the function.

```
var rezept = '';
$("select#rezept").change(function () {
    rezept = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    console.log(rezept);
}
```